# Parsing XML in Python with ElementTree - findall

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.findall) to try to get only the values for certain elements.

This is an example of the structure of my XML:

```
<ListOrdersRequest>
    <ListOrdersResult>
        <Orders>
            <Order>
                ...
                <ElementIWant>value_I_want</ElementIWant>
            </Order>
            <Order>
                ...
                <ElementIWant>value_I_want</ElementIWant>
            </Order>
            ...
        </Orders>
    </ListOrdersResult>
</ListOrdersRequest>
```

I have this entire XML file saved to string variable `response_data`, and I only want the values from element `ElementIWant`.

Working off [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example) example in the documentation, I've tried something like this:

```
values = ET.fromstring(response_data).findall(".//ElementIWant")
print values
```

But it only returns an empty list `[]`. I've tried other things to no success. Any ideas? All advice appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: This doesn't print anything either:

```
values = ET.fromstring(response_data)

for i in values.findall(".//ElementIWant"):
    print i.text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `text` property to print only the value of  a particular tag.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
response_data = '''<ListOrdersRequest>
    <ListOrdersResult>
        <Orders>
            <Order>
                ...
                <ElementIWant>value_I_want</ElementIWant>
            </Order>
            <Order>
                ...
                <ElementIWant>value_I_want</ElementIWant>
            </Order>
            ...
        </Orders>
    </ListOrdersResult>
</ListOrdersRequest>'''
for i in ET.fromstring(response_data).findall(".//ElementIWant"):
    print i.text
```

**Output:**

```
value_I_want
value_I_want
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ran this from the command line and it worked, but I need to run it from a script. I tried this, but it still returns an empty list: `values = ET.fromstring(response_data)

for i in values.findall(".//BuyerEmail"):
 print i.text`

Comment: Worked for me, too.  If you could post a complete Python script that is giving you an emply list, that would help.  If I had to guess, I would guess that `response_data` does not actually contain the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
[BeautifulStoneSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing%20a%20Document)
or 
[ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm)

I used BeautifulStoneSoup a couple of years back to parse an XML for a project, it should help you.

Comment: The OP is asking a question about the use of ElementTree. I'm not sure recommending the use of ElementTree is going to help.  OTOH, I've never seen BeautifulStoneSoup before, so thanks are due for pointing that alternative out to us.

Comment: My apologies for not reading the post to full. I accept your down vote.